# How to write loop Using Plot syntax in R

Tags: r

I need a help, If I have five columns in CSV file, I want to draw charts using R studio, These charts it should be considering the first column is the X-axes and the other columns are the Y-axis , then I will have Four charts Bay applying a loop, Please if you can give some answers to loop It in R studio,
I have tried, but I didn't get the object, the plots I need, are line plots

I expect an answers could be useful

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
                   y1 = rnorm(10),
                   y2 = rnorm(10),
                   y3 = rnorm(10),
                   y4 = rnorm(10))

make_plot <- function(df, y) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = .data[[y]] )) +
    geom_line()
}

lapply(names(data)[-1],
       make_plot,
       df = data)
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[3]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[4]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: @Jon if this answer does what you are looking for, please 'accept' it. If it does not, please elaborate and explain what you are looking for that this answer does not provide.